# Android: Horizontal list view on custom adaptor

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-custom-view

I am developing an application in which i required horizontal list view with custom adapter. I tried a demo from the [Link](http://sandyandroidtutorials.blogspot.in/2013/06/horizontal-listview-tutorial.html).

The demo is running fine. But when i implemented the same code in my application the horizontal scroll is not working.

My custom adapter is having the layout whose one item covers whole screen width and around half of the height of the screen.

When i run my code the first item is visible perfectly. But the second item in not visible as the screen is not scrolling. I implemented the same code in same way as given in the link.

Where i am wrong please let me know, or what should i do now please suggest me.

Comment: Please post your "item" layout and activity layout

Comment: That is really old code, use RecyclerView instead and set it to horizontal.

Answer (score 1):

> layout whose one item covers whole screen width and around half of the height of the screen

I think you should use a ViewPager for this:
http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html

If you don't like to use Fragments you could try RecyclerView (like jvrodrigues suggested) with a horizontal LinearLayoutManager (available in the support library).
See: https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html

hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

After reading this post, I have implemented my own Horizontal listview. You can find it:[link](http://www.dev-smart.com/archives/34)